I get FAILURE when i installed firebase in flutter
I debugged with Android Studio but if i debug with chrome no error. Error that:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)


I used with Android Studio.
I installed firebase_core 3.1.0. Used 'flutter pub add firebase_core'.

I solved like that
Go android/app/build.gradle then add these codes.
 dependencies {


 //...other dependencies in Module...

 implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))

}

